# Where is the ListView?

Tags: android, listview, master-detail

I've created a Master-Detail application from the given Android templates. I need to create a method to delete an item on longclick, but all the tutorials I've found on the subject involve

```
getListView().setOnItemLongClickListener...
// and so on
```

My problem is, I don't know where the ListView is! When I run the program with no modifications, just the base template Android creates, it runs fine. When I add "getListView" to the onCreate method, the program crashes.

There's obviously a ListView, because I see a list, but I don't know where in the default template it's buried. It's not listed in any xml or java files, so I don't know how to access it.

This may be a stupid question, but I've been at this for hours, and I would really appreciate any advice.

Comment: What is the Activity base class which Activity extends from it?

Comment: I've got ItemListActivity and ItemListFragment. I would have thought it would be in the fragment.

Comment: Did you initialise your listview? If the activity is a ListActivity, than call ListView lv = getListView(); and then set a OnLongClickListener. And of course you have to setAdapter to manage your ListView's content

Comment: I did not initialize it, because the list shows up when I run the app, so I thought it already was. My ItemListActivity extends FragmentActivity, and ItemListFragment extends ListFragment. I thought android would have set up the template to work as it should, and our teacher didn't mention any of this, he just showed us how the default template works.

Comment: `getListView` is a method from `ListFragment`. I would be quite surprised if that was never mentioned in any tutorial you read (if so you should use other tutorials)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you've created from Master-Detail template, you have a Fragment generated that extends **ListFragment**. Trying to call getListView() from **onCreate()** method in the Fragment will result in the following exception:

```
java.lang.IllegalStateException: Content view not yet created
```

You can't call this method before the view of the Fragment has been created (as the exception states). You can use it in the **onViewCreated()** method (or any method called after onViewCreated() was called). Hope this helps.

Comment: Turns out this was exactly my problem. Thank you so much!

Answer (score 0):

getListView is a method from ListActivity. If you are not extending that, you won't see it

Comment: If I'm using fragments, should the ItemListActivity be the one to extend ListActivity? It's currently extending FragmentActivity, and since that's what android's template says I assumed that's what it should be for the fragments to work.

Comment: ListFragment is probably where you want it, but it depends on your code.